# Why max CPU usage is capped in Windows 10 just few percents below 100%?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, task-manager

I wonder why sometimes max CPU usage in Windows 10 is capped just few percents below 100%. Max CPU power is at 100% in Control panel/Power options applet.

Is it just wrong reporting? You just can't reach 100% no matter how you try. I am jus saturating CPU with few instances of "while ($true){}" in PowerShell. There is no thermal throtling. It is not only happens on this particular system it do happen on some other systems too.

It is not that it is a huge problem but I wonder why is it so because my google fu seems to be too weak here and I am curious why is it so?

[image]

Comment: My workstation at work routinely says the CPU usage is 100%, why exactly are you concerned, by this behavior?  It absolutely is possible to have 100% usage on Windows 10.  **You absolutely do not want that to happen.**

Comment: Absolutely. On the other hand, I've come across several Lenovo laptop (T460, T470 and T480) where the MIN CPU percentage was also set to 100% in all power modes. The fan would scream bloody murder all the time, and the users would too, in my ears... I had to reset a few dozens with a script a few months ago, so I wouldn't be surprised if that were also the case for the PC of our Russian friend here...

Comment: Guys, again this is not problem per se. I am just curious. Can one be? And @Didier I am not russian friend. Interface is in Ukrainian. Are you Italian?

Comment: Are you running something intensive which you would expect 100% utilization? How are temps on the CPU? Perhaps there is some thermal throttling going on. If that's not it, try right clicking on the graph and changing to show Logical processors instead of Overall utilization. I'm not sure what the Ukranian would be but it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUWiS.png

Comment: If the computer only using the CPU. or maybe using a bit the disk?

Comment: @iskra, given what recently happened between the Ukraine and Russia, my apologies! Your PC interface being in Cyrillic, I thought you were Russian. As for the rest, as Ramhound mentioned, your PC CPU flirting with the 100% mark all the time is no trivial matter, because it denotes a possible problem. Can you check your power settings and tell us what the MINIMUM CPU level is? PS: FWIW, I'm not Italian... :-)

Comment: The Intel Pentium T4500 is an old processor released in 2010. The CPU is probably not entirely adequate to support a complex operating system such as Windows 10. This could be the reason for the high operating frequency of the processor.

Comment: @iskra Thanks for your edit. I tried this myself and I was able to hit 100% with while true in PowerShell so it shouldn't be capped. Are you seeing both cores stuck at ~94% or is one maxed out at 100% and the other has room left?

Comment: Both are capped at 95%. it is maximum I was able to get to with two Prime95 threads and few  while true instances. It just this way on some systems. I was not able to find anything regarding it hence the question here

Comment: @Didier min CPU level is at 5% though I don't see CPU is actually going lower than 2GHz even or lowest load. Do you think this might be some SpeedStep mishap? and btw you are using latin letters I thought you might be italian (or maybe american then)

Comment: I think you are mistaking the percentage of maximum CPU clock speed and the percentage of CPU usage. The former refers to how high your CPU can go in terms of frequency (clock speed) relative to its factory value (e.g.: your Pentium has a max clock speed of 2.3GHz; apply 90% to that, and you bring its actual clock speed to 2.07GHz as you are underclocking it), whereas the latter refers to how busy your CPU actually is (94% of its CPU cycles in your screenshot, for example), regardless of how fast it runs in terms of clock speed. Can you restart your machine and post new screens afterwards?

Comment: @Didier, as you can see it is both mentioned cases here. System cant get 100% saturating on any core and CPU is not getting to it's designated GHz speed at the same time

Comment: Precisely. You reach (near) 100% CPU *occupation* AND your CPU isn't delivering full (clock speed) power, but that's a moot point. The real question, as was mentioned by Ramhound earlier, is, how come your CPU pegs at almost 100% occupation all the time. That isn't normal. It could be malware, could be high interrupts due to a hardware-related issue (over-burdened network card, for example, or an external drive taking too much power AND bandwidth), could be a peripheral needs a new driver, could be a lot of things, but you shouldn't let it slide. Check interrupts in Resource Manager first.